# How to offset visible cells only

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a VBA code in which I must get the row down by one, from the table header, for an exact column. For this I use the Offset(1) property of the ranges. The problem is I am working with filtered data and the offset gets me to `G2` for example, instead of going to `Gx`, where `x` is the first visible row after the table header. How do i better accomplish this? Thank you

Comment: Maybe you can try `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` to go through the visible cells

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this:

```
Sub selectFirstVisibleCell()

    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row

    Range("G1:G" & lastRow).Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas(1).Rows(1).Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. This is great and exactly what i needed. I will learn from your answer

Answer (score 0):

```
ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)(1).Row
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Code-only answers are not particularly helpful. Please include a brief description of how this code solves the problem.

Comment: Answer's are great. But for best practices, please provide an explanation. You only posting code makes the OP and future commers copy and paste your answer without understanding the logic behind the answer. Please provide an answer with some explanation. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the very same problem by modifing @TheJaswi code, as it was not working for me and going to very first column header offsetting to visible rows:

```
'Getting Total columns count in the given table
col = Worksheets(1).ListObjects(1).ListColumns.Count
ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1, col - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)(1).Select
```

Answer (score 0):

I have got a mathematical VBA solution to get to the first visible cell in filtered data.

```
    Range("A10000").End(xlUp).Select
    
    last_row = ActiveCell.Row
    
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
    
    VisCellCount = WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(3, Selection)
    
    first_row = last_row - VisCellCount + 2
    
    Range("A" & first_row).Select
```